# Drop-down box in JSP Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC based Java Web App. On one of the pages, I need to have a drop down box - example Student names-which will help me search for Student details. The screen also has "Add", "Edit" or "Delete" functions on it- in this example Student records can be added, edited or deleted. The issue that I am having is when a Student is added, the drop-down box which I have on the "Search" does not get populated with the latest Student Added. Only if I go out of the application and come back in does it get populated.

On the code side side I have the following:

I have a Controller class with a method `getStudentNamesList()`

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "testModelAttribute")
   public StudentNamesDTO getNamesList() {
    StudentNamesDTO studentNamesDTO = plStudentDelegate
                .getStudentList();
    //m.addAttribute("interface", interfaceNamesDTO);
    return studentNamesDTO;

}
```

On the JSP page I have the following:

```
<div class="wf2-field">
    <div class="wf2-fieldl">
    <div id="setfieldCust" class="wf2-field medium">
    <label>Interface <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="wf2-field-body">
    <div class="wf2-field-state">
    <form:select id="cstSlct" path="studentNm">
    <form:option value="">Select One</form:option>
        <form:options items="${testAttribute.studentNmList}" />
    </form:select>
</div>
```

I do see the method `getNamesList()` being called and the retrieve being done from the database. But for some reason the drop-down box on the JSP page is not being updated with the value.

Please help

Comment: Post the compleet code for controller and jsp

Comment: Where is testAttribute from?

Comment: I simply used this name for the  attribute .I use this name to populate the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery` for this:

```
$("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue");
```

Place this code in function, that will call with Student Adding

Answer (score 0):

call getStudentList() in method from you are getting back after adding student record.call methos after insertion.